# Acne pimples on face

Tags: personal-care

I have acne on my face from few years.i have used so many things for this take medicines from skin specialist but not useful at all kindly suggest me anything. I have oily skin.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site. Just wanted to point out that Health tips are outside the scope of lifehacks.se, I'm afraid - this question would probably be better off posed on another site in the .stackexchange network

Comment: I didn't make the rules, and I'm sorry that you perceived my comment as unfriendly and unhelpful - from my perspective it was merely factual; lifehacks is frequently treated as a dumping ground for queries that don't have an obviously more relevant community. This diminishes the experience for all and can cause communities to be closed. For health issues we specifically recommend you contact a qualified healthcare provider who can look at you in person; giving health advice over the internet based on a limited amateur description of symptoms is extremely unwise and no doctor would condone it

Comment: @user5948 Have you tried using a Clarisonic? That product did more for me than anything else in getting rid of acne. Don't buy a knock off brand; buy the real thing. Use twice x day. They are worth the money.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clean your hands and face as often as possible.

Stop touching your face with your fingers all the time.

Use a clean pillow-case. Clean it more often.

Stop eating potato chips and other greasy/salty snacks.

Drink a lot of water all the time. (A LOT) If you don't like to drink water, drink it until you like it. The more the better, seriously. Poisoning yourself with "too much water" is very difficult. Water will dilute the pollution inside you and flush the bad stuff out.

If you do eat salty and greasy foods, compensate by drinking a lot of water after.

Drink water when you drink alcohol. (one glass of beer, one glass of water) This will not prevent you from being drunk, don't worry. It does prevent hangover however.

If you are a teenager, consider that you are in the worst age for this, time will help.

There might not be a miracle solution for you but all these can help.

If you are over 20 years old and still experience acne problems even with applying these methods, consider talking to a doctor.

Source: my own experience. When I stopped eating BBQ chips every night before sleep, it magically went away.

Edit: Noticed from your profile that you work with computers, like me. A lot of people in this field sit all day long and can develop unhealthy habits. I don't know if that is your case. Try to be healthy. If you are fat and eat a lot of fast-foods, the acne might be only one symptom of a general unhealthy lifestyle. You cannot correct just that one symptom, you need to address the root cause and be more healthy overall. Try to do a MINIMUM of exercise EVERY day, just walking 20 mins is something, compared to nothing at all.

Answer (score 2):

There are many factors that play into how much acne one has (including many that are likely beyond your control), but there are a few general guidelines that may help.

1. Wash your face twice daily (morning and night). The type of cleanser you use is important, but not as important as consistently washing your face. Try using a soap or face wash that targets oily skin.
2. Use clean cloths on your face. Change your pillowcases regularly, and avoid reusing towels on your face. Similarly, don’t use a towel on your face that you use on other parts of your body, as this can unnecessarily spread bacteria.
3. Exercises, eat right, and drink water. This is good advice in general, but it is also helpful for your overall skin health. Avoid oily foods if you have oily skin.
4. Never sleep with makeup on. If you wear makeup, use a separate makeup remover (other than just soap) and follow up with a normal face cleanse.
5. Try other products. It can take up to six weeks for a product to begin working, so it may help to stick with one product for a while. Additionally, you may want to try face products other than soap. Finding the right products for exfoliating, toning, and moisturizing can be a challenge, but incorporating these extra steps into your face routine can be helpful even if they are generic drugstore brands.
6. Check with your physician about other health concerns. If your acne is “normal” for your age, chances are you can help the problem by using some of the aforementioned steps. If it seems unusual, you may have a hormone imbalance and possible other issues. If you suspect something isn’t right, it’s always better to consult with an expert!

Comment: I hear your frustration.  Our son got the acne gene from both of us and has been struggling for years to find a solution that works. Your oily skin sounds like my son's. He could wash many times a day, change bedding every day and there would be no difference.  However, there is hope. Maybe......  first rule out allergic reaction as acne can be a result of a reaction to food or something that you come in contact with.   With our son , the next step is supplements. There are many out there that "might" help. Everyone has different skin.  Collegen seems to be what is working for my son.